# Array of strings to object keys strongly typed

Tags: typescript

Is it possible with typescript to have the following function:

```
function someFunction(keys: string[]): ???{
    ...
}
```

That can infer the returned type based on the key strings passed into it:

```
var thing = someFunction(["a", "b", "c"]);

// type should be: { "a": typeX, "b": typeX, "c": typeX };

var thing2 = someFunction(["d", "e", "f", "g"]);

// type should be: { "d": typeX, "e": typeX, "f": typeX, "g": typeX };
```

typeX is some other object and can be chnaged.

Comment: Can you clarify *how* `typeX` is changed? How is the compiler supposed to determine which `typeX` a particular invocation of `someFunction` is returning?

Comment: Thanks for responding meriton. TypeX is just some type I have. I'd like to create an object whose keys are from the array of strings and the type of each keys value is some type I have in my system. TypeX is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a concrete example, I'll proceed as if `typeX` is the following type:

```
type typeX = { x: number };
```

You could make `someFunction()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function whose `keys` are an array of values of type `K`, where `K` is the generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be assignable to `string`.  In practice when you call `someFunction()`, the compiler will *infer* `K` to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) of the values you pass in.  Armed with `K`, you can represent the output type of the function as the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{[P in K]: typeX}`, meaning its keys are from `K` and the values are of type `typeX`.  You could also represent this as `Record<K, typeX>` using the built-in [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
function someFunction<K extends string>(keys: K[]) {
  const ret = {} as { [P in K]: typeX };
  for (const key of keys) {
    ret[key] = { x: Math.random() };
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Note that I used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to claim that `ret` is of the desired type.  That's because when it's initialized as an empty object `{}`, the compiler would rightfully complain that it doesn't match that type (it's missing all the properties).  Since we plan to rectify that before `ret` is returned, we use `as` to tell the compiler not to worry about it.

---

Now you can test it out:

```
var thing = someFunction(["a", "b", "c"]);
/* var thing: {
    a: typeX;
    b: typeX;
    c: typeX;
} */
console.log(thing);
/* {
  "a": {
    "x": 0.6910903555102567
  },
  "b": {
    "x": 0.44486605600057627
  },
  "c": {
    "x": 0.5541700451481854
  }
} */

var thing2 = someFunction(["d", "e", "f", "g"]);
/* var thing2: {
    d: typeX;
    e: typeX;
    f: typeX;
    g: typeX;
} */
console.log(thing2);
/* {
  "d": {
    "x": 0.7189809491373391
  },
  "e": {
    "x": 0.5863094355337393
  },
  "f": {
    "x": 0.2102034346398125
  },
  "g": {
    "x": 0.6131703986848467
  }
} */
```

Looks good.  Your values are of the proper types both at runtime and as seen by the compiler.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBKkBpQLxQN5QB4C4oDsCuAtgEYQBOUAvgNwCwAUPQGZ44DGwAlgPY5QDOXAhABiLdtxwAeANJQI6YBBwATPv2CkOOAOYA+ABQBrCCD7ZpAbQC6ASlT0oUVjz7AopCG+QoKUAIZqaBYAClBaUNJW2LAQCNQOUIxc5PrOOK5QxiBQXIyZJnx2KAmOHsAWWVZIqBjYALJ+wAAWAHSkfiqC+nbxdI4UCWV4pLxltHQDDFMAbn7kzVra1QJComycPPoWAER+2wA0UNtEB0es27bjAPQAVFCz802L2MV9jv7R4LHj71BEn-Afu9WADvvRfDcrvQ0gIADYQFqwrjafQLHQ2a53V6OXbbF4lI7oPFQAAMLQAbABOACMJMpJIAzABWFm0gBMTPJAHYEhR9gljsTse9tkTsGSACxSgAc5PJJM5JKVTK55LZPLefIF53xbxxYtJLRZEupXKVEqZ1Il0up0qZEt54KgkPo9AeMCeOjZy0EIjEGxwW22ylO2wgocYoe0Fwx9Fu9zmHsWbN1v2UoLgQMcEAzWcSuYJ2gLE2dULoMK48MRyNRnu0bNjdHjwuDQoJouJZK5tsp0rpEppDK5DIZNN5-LeYbbesJnaNsoZ-eZTJHw8pDPHAsjqZFBrJbPZjIlDIl5NHNo5m8n0Z3+rn5OpDNNjN75Ol1tPGv6TpddCAA)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by combining [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
function someFunction<K extends string>(keys: K[]) {
    const o = {} as {[A in K]: TypeX};
    for (const k of keys) {
      o[k] = new TypeX();
    }
    return o;
}

const x = someFunction(["foo", "bar"]);
x.foo; // ok
x.bar; // ok
x.weird; // Property 'weird' does not exist on type '{ foo: TypeX; bar: TypeX }'
```

Comment: Thanks Meriton, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, take a look into generic functions in typescript
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: I'm unsure of how to do it, do you have an example?